# Send to back object that created at run time

Tags: c#, wpf, z-index

I have a page that in this page i have one image and at run time i add 3 buttons but these button come to front of image. how can i send these button to back. i use Panel.SetZindex but not works. thank you.

Comment: Please show your code/XAML.

Comment: Have you tried by increasing Panel.SetZindex of image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you also used `Panel.SetZindex` for image control? I think you would have used it just for buttons not for image thats why buttons are still coming in front of image control.

You should set z-index of buttons to least possible value and the z-index of image to highest possible value so that image would comes in front.

Use following code:

```
Panel.SetZindex(button1,0);
Panel.SetZindex(button2,1);
Panel.SetZindex(button3,2);

Panel.SetZindex(image,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set buttons z-index property to lowest possible number and then add it at run time.